# No module named 'urlparse'” when I use import urlparse

Tags: python

I'm having troubleto run this code, can anyone help me?

```
import sys, urllib, re, urlparse
from urllib import urlretrieve
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

it say's ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: this is python2 code, you're trying to run it using python3

Answer (score 2):

For python3 use the below

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Comment: Thank i just learned python and didn't notice it. It works once I changed it